# SQL Remove all leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, padleft

My join returns null because I am not able to remove the leading zeros. Basically, I am trying to replace the `pol.Policy_Number` with `src.Policy_Number` for a large number of policies. Is there a way I can remove the leading 0s in the `ON` statement for `src.Policy_Number`? I think Padding is needed, but I am new to SQL so any help would be much appreciated. That `pol` policy numbers always equal `src` policy numbers if it was not for the leading 0s in pol
This is not a duplicate. I am not looking for a `select`. I need to put padding next to the ON statement so any leading 0s from `src`.Policy_Number will be removed so the `JOIN` can return rows. Please don't close the question a duplicate

```
 UPDATE pol
SET pol.Policy_Number = src.Policy_Number
FROM Policy_Table pol
INNER JOIN SourceTable src
 on  pol.Policy_Number =src.Policy_Number--00000000000000ABCD200,0000000000000EFT200
 Where src.Policy_Number IN('ABCD200','EFT200')
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am not looking for a `select`. I need to put padding next to the `ON` statement so any leading 0s from `src`.Policy_Number will be removed so the `JOIN` can return rows. Please don't close the question a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UPDATE pol
SET pol.Policy_Number = src.Policy_Number
FROM Policy_Table pol
INNER JOIN SourceTable src
on  pol.Policy_Number =replace(ltrim(replace(src.Policy_Number,'0',' ')),' ','0')
```